# firebase asincrono graba registros como no quiero

Tags: android

Tengo este codigo. Lo que realiza es lee mfirestorecostaleros pasar 5 veces (5 registros) por el for y despues ejecuta mfirestoreasistencia por lo cual la variable gmidcostalero cuando entra en mfirestoreasistencia siempre tiene el mismo valor (el ultimo registro leido).

He probado con las corrutinas de Kotlin pero estoy programando en java.

Ya se que firebase es asincrono y por eso hace esto.

¿Teneis alguna solucion para que lo ejecute y lo grabe bien ?

Gracias

```
mfirestorecostaleros.collection( "Costaleros" ).whereEqualTo("activo", "S").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          for (QueryDocumentSnapshot qDScostaleros : task.getResult()) {
              gmidcostalero = qDScostaleros.getString( "idcostalero" );

              mfirestoreasistencia.collection( "Asistencias" ).whereEqualTo("idcostalero", gmidcostalero).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                 @Override
                  public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                      if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                         // grabar en asistencia
                         Map<String, Object> mapasistencia = new HashMap<>();
                         mapasistencia.put("idcostalero", gmidcostalero );
                         mapasistencia.put("ordenasistencia", "1" );
                         mapasistencia.put("ensayo", "Procesion" );
                         mapasistencia.put("si", "N" );
                         mapasistencia.put("no", "S" );
                         mapasistencia.put("justificado", "N" );
                         DocumentReference newCityRefasisprocesion = mfirestoreasistenciagrabar.collection("Asistencias").document();
                         String myIdprocesion = newCityRefasisprocesion.getId();
                         mapasistencia.put("idasistencia", myIdprocesion );
                         newCityRefasisprocesion.set(mapasistencia);
                      }
                  }
             });
          }
      }
  }
```

});

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende.  Si lo que quieres es obtener datos asíncronos para luego usarlos en otra parte, entonces al leer los datos guárdalos en un objeto (si son varios en una lista) y luego, al terminar de leer los datos llama al siguiente método que usará esos datos pasando en parámetro la lista que habrás llenado previamente.  Otra posibilidad es usar  devoluciones de llamada (callback), pero esto es un poquito más complejo de entender.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> ejecuta `mfirestoreasistencia` por lo cual la variable `gmidcostalero`
> cuando entra en `mfirestoreasistencia` siempre tiene el mismo valor

al ver el código, se puede notar que el problema se debe a sincronía, ya que obtienes el valor de `gmidcostalero`, pero la respuesta del mètodo `onSuccess()` es asíncrona, es decir que no es instantánea. Al llamar este mètodo probablemente ya se realizò la iteraciòn de los 5 valores y podrìas siempre tener el ùltimo valor en la variable `gmidcostalero`

```
mfirestoreasistencia.collection( "Asistencias" ).whereEqualTo("idcostalero", gmidcostalero).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                 @Override
                  public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                      if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                         // grabar en asistencia
                         Map<String, Object> mapasistencia = new HashMap<>();
                         mapasistencia.put("idcostalero", gmidcostalero );
                         ...
                         ...
                         ...
                      }
                  }
    });
```

Una forma de solucionar rápidamente este problema es que se mantenga en cada iteraciòn la referencia al valor de `gmidcostalero`, es declarándola como final, para que una vez inicializada no pierda su valor en cada iteraciòn. Recuerda renombrar la variable

```
mfirestorecostaleros.collection( "Costaleros" ).whereEqualTo("activo", "S").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          for (QueryDocumentSnapshot qDScostaleros : task.getResult()) {
              final String locgmidcostalero = qDScostaleros.getString( "idcostalero" );

              mfirestoreasistencia.collection( "Asistencias" ).whereEqualTo("idcostalero", locgmidcostalero).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                 @Override
                  public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                      if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                         // grabar en asistencia
                         Map<String, Object> mapasistencia = new HashMap<>();
                         mapasistencia.put("idcostalero", locgmidcostalero );
                         mapasistencia.put("ordenasistencia", "1" );
                         mapasistencia.put("ensayo", "Procesion" );
                         mapasistencia.put("si", "N" );
                         mapasistencia.put("no", "S" );
                         mapasistencia.put("justificado", "N" );
                         DocumentReference newCityRefasisprocesion = mfirestoreasistenciagrabar.collection("Asistencias").document();
                         String myIdprocesion = newCityRefasisprocesion.getId();
                         mapasistencia.put("idasistencia", myIdprocesion );
                         newCityRefasisprocesion.set(mapasistencia);
                      }
                  }
             });
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Pues si que era facil. Al final de tantas vueltas lo habia realizado con un adapter sale igual pero mas largo y complicado.

Comment: Excelente, recuerda que si esta respuesta ayudo a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, puedes marcarla como solución , revisa [tour], saludos.